# Set conditional formatting expression using VBA variables?

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to add conditional formatting to a range from VBA using the following statement:

```
r.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=AND($AYQ4<=D$3;$AYR4>=D$3)"
```

Now the problem is that instead of having AYQ, 4, D, 3 and AYR I have the following VBA variables:

```
lDatesAndHeadersRow = 3
the first row of range r = 4

the first column of range r = D
lStartDateCol = column number of AYQ
lEndDateCol = column number of AYR
```

Is there any way for me to use my VBA variables instead of normal cell references in the following expression `Formula1:="=AND($AYQ4<=D$3;$AYR4>=D$3)"`?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot. Variables exists only in the context of the macro they are defined into, once copied in the cell they become strings.

Comment: Thank you answering! Copying the variables into a cell is not what I wanted to do. I've edited my post and hopefully made it clearer.

Comment: Sorry, I still don't get it then. Do you have a range and want to find out what are its first row and first column so that you can use these in the formula?

Comment: I want to set conditional formatting to the range using VBA. I know that I can write Formula1:="=AND($AYQ4<=D$3;$AYR4>=D$3)". But I don't want to do that because all of those columns might change. So instead of hard coding the columns and rows I want to use the VBA variables lDatesAndHeadersRow, r.row, r.column, lStartDateCol and lEndDateCol. But I can't figure out how to do that.